# Javascript: Trouble with manipulating document element (undefined)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that is enabled through an onkeyup listener attributed to an input element:

```
<input type="text" id="s-name" onkeyup="filter_name();filter_event_nums();" placeholder="Search string..">
```

My javascript function is supposed to loop through the li.days elements (which are used to format a 31 day calendar) and for every form (child element) check if input string exists in div (class="event") which is the form element's child. So the hierarchy is:

```
 <li class="days">
    <form>
       <div class="event">
       </div>
    </form>
 </li>
```

My code is this:

```
function filter_event_nums() {
    let forms=0, events, event_num, counter=0, txtValue, k = 0, i = 0;
    var input = document.getElementById("s-name");
    var filter = input.value;
    var days = document.querySelectorAll('li.days');    
    for (i = 0; i <= days.length; i++) {
        let forms = days[i].getElementsByTagName('form');
        counter=0;
        for (k = 0; k <= forms.length; k++) {
            var d = document.querySelectorAll('li.days')[i];
            var text_data = forms[k].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
            if (text_data.includes(filter)===true) { 
                counter+=1;
            }

        }
        event_num = days[i].querySelector('.eventnum');
        event_num.innerHTML = counter;
    }
}
```

The debugger indicates that forms[k] (second line of second loop) is undefined and of course, it doesn't work. Please.. for god's sake, enlighten me.
I will take my chances and say that (my) actual html is not needed to understand this problem but if someone things it is, i will post.

Comment: in your loops, eg `i <= days.length` should use `<` rather than `<=`. The same with the other loop. This is because you don't want the index to go up to the length of the array - because indices start from 0, the last is the length minus 1. If you try to "go beyond", as you are, you'll end up accessing `undefined` instead of an actual array element.

Comment: Thank you so god damn much, this solved it. You da best